# Sorting Array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

I thought I could do it the way that has been stated below. However when I sort it this way the output is the values in hexadecimal values, instead of the string pointing to "item" in the array @menu. What I want to achieve is to sort it by "item-name"

```
my @menu = (
        { item => "Blazer", price => 100, color => "Brown" },
        { item => "Jeans",  price => 50, color => "Blue" },
        { item => "Shawl",  price => 30, color => "Red" },
        { item => "Suit",   price => 40, color => "Black" },
        { item => "Top",    price => 25, color => "White" },
    );    

    my @test = sort {item } @menu;

    foreach (@test){
    print $_;

    }
```

Comment: Did you try `perldoc -f sort` first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `print $_` prints the string value of each hash reference, so you will get something like `HASH(0x1d33524)`. You need to print the fields of each hash that you're interested in.

Also, you need a proper comparison expression inside the `sort` block. Just giving the name of a hash key won't do anything useful.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @menu = (
  { item => 'Blazer', price => 100, color => 'Brown' },
  { item => 'Jeans',  price => 50,  color => 'Blue' },
  { item => 'Shawl',  price => 30,  color => 'Red' },
  { item => 'Suit',   price => 40,  color => 'Black' },
  { item => 'Top',    price => 25,  color => 'White' },
);

my @test = sort { $a->{item} cmp $b->{item} } @menu;

for ( @test ) {
  print "@{$_}{qw/ item price color /}\n";
}
```

**output**

```
Blazer 100 Brown
Jeans 50 Blue
Shawl 30 Red
Suit 40 Black
Top 25 White
```

---

**Update**

If all you want is a sorted list of the item field values then you can write this more simply

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @menu = (
  { item => 'Blazer', price => 100, color => 'Brown' },
  { item => 'Jeans',  price => 50,  color => 'Blue' },
  { item => 'Shawl',  price => 30,  color => 'Red' },
  { item => 'Suit',   price => 40,  color => 'Black' },
  { item => 'Top',    price => 25,  color => 'White' },
);

my @test = sort map { $_->{item} } @menu;

print "$_\n" for @test;
```

**output**

```
Blazer
Jeans
Shawl
Suit
Top
```

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the curlies needs to be an expression that returns the whether the element `$a` should appear before the element `$b` in the final result.
See `perldoc -f sort`for details.

As the elements are hash references, and you want to sort on the string value of key `item` in those, you need to load that value for comparing

```
sort { $a->{item} cmp $b->{item} }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `sort BLOCK LIST` is the block that compares two members of the list, not the way how to extract the things to compare. See [sort](http://p3rl.org/sort).

```
my @test = sort { $a->{item} cmp $b->{item} } @menu;
```

[Sort::Key](http://p3rl.org/Sort::Key) allows you to specify "what to sort by", not "how to compare elements".

```
use Sort::Key qw{ keysort };
# ...
my @test = keysort { $_->{item} } @menu;
```

In your code without [strict](http://p3rl.org/strict), the string `"item"` is used to compare the elements, which doesn't really change the order in any way. What you see in the output is the representation of the members of the array, i.e. hash references. If you want to see the items only, use

```
for (@test) {
    print $_->{item}, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See also `List::UtilsBy`:

```
use List::UtilsBy 'sort_by';

my @test = sort_by { $_->{item} } @menu;
```